# DataTriggerBehavior is not working for null values

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am trying to set visibility of my stackpanel to collapsed if value is null, but DataTriggerBehavior is not changing it's visibility value, If I change value to something else than it work's, below is the xaml for that:

```
 <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
     <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding Name}"
                                 Value="{x:Null}">
     <Core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=spName}"
                                 PropertyName="Visibility"
                                 Value="Collapsed" />
                    </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
 </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Comment: Have checked if the value is `null`? Have you tried to also check `Value=""`

Comment: Yes, I did tried that but still visibilty was not changing.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a simple converter which presumes `Name` is a `String` and returns an empty String if value is null else returns the value as a `String`

```
public class NullToEmptyStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value == null)            
            return "";            
        else
            return value.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And your xaml will reference `NullToEmptyStringConverter` NB local is the namespace where I've created the converter class it maybe different in your app

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:NullToEmptyStringConverter x:Key="NullToEmptyStringConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

and your `DataTrigger`

```
<Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
 <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource NullToEmptyStringConverter}}"
                             Value="">
     <Core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=spName}"
                             PropertyName="Visibility"
                             Value="Collapsed" />
 </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
```

Comment: Yes, Converter is the only option right now, but wanna know why DataTriggerBehavior is not working for null.

Comment: seems like a fault with the Trigger itself looking at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23728327/datatriggerbehavior-doesnt-work-with-enum)